# Jira API POST and Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: json, api, powershell, jira

Using Jira API 2 and PowerShell 5 `Invoke-RestMethod` I can successfully execute GET, but I keep getting a `(400) Bad Request` when attempting POST method to create an issue in my project.

```bsh
$user    = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("me:mypassword")
$headers = @{Authorization = "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($user)}
$data    = Get-Content D:\scripts\powershell\issue.txt 

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://agile.mycompany.com/rest/api/2/issue/" -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Body $data
```

`$data` variable is well-formed JSON for Jira:

```json
{ 
    "fields":
    {
        "project":{"Key": "ITS"},
        "summary":"Rest Test 1",
        "issuetype":{"name": "Task"},
        "assignee":{"key": "myusername"},
        "priority":{"id": "3"},
        "description":
            "||Host Name||IP Address||Comments|| 
             |some-pc|192.168.1.1| |",
        "duedate": "2016-09-11"
    }
}
```

I am the project owner, so this isn't a permissions issue.

Comment: The code looks good to me. Do you have access to the server logs? What do they say about this? Did you try using `curl` instead of `Invoke-RestMethod`? Do the requests look the same in Fiddler?

Comment: Ansgar, I tried using curl for windows.  same sort of issue - GET works, but POST...well, it doesn't fail or succeed.  The script runs, and just never either succeeds or fails.  I'll do this on a linux box with curl and see what happens.

I've actually been trying to use the jira-ruby gem, but my connection object fails intermittently and I have no idea why.

Comment: all right.  Tried with curl on a centos server.

{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"project":"project is required"}}


I added the "self" and "ID" KV pairs to the "project" field, same error all 3 times.

Comment: Then I'd say the issue is either with your data or with the server side. Server logs should provide more information if you have access to them. I'd also try simplifying the data to check if something in the data is the root cause.

Comment: The problem seems to be with your project field, the schema requires the key to be "id", yours is "Key" (note that it's also capitalized) https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-createIssue

Comment: going through catalina.out, I'm getting this every time I submit a POST, via cural from a RHEL server or via PS from my laptop:

2016-08-13 13:51:00,930 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-4 INFO anonymous    PC [atlassian.mail.incoming.mailfetcherservice] PC[10101]: 

No idea what the mailfetcherservice has to do with POST requests, but I see that line every time I try to POST.

Comment: Jan, I've tried key and id, and Key and ID...same issues.  For what it's worth, key and id both come through as lower case on a GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  The issue was that I was CAPITALIZING the first letter of the field names.  Apparently, Jira is very sensitive to CASE.  **Trondh** - thank you for the recommendation to use postman.  The errors that were getting generated by postman from the failed API calls were very concise.

Answer (score 0):

Get-content is tricky, because it will actually result in a array of strings, where each line in your text file is an object in that array. The best way to get around that is probably using .Net's file read methods instead:

`$data = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("D:\scripts\powershell\issue.txt")`

btw, you can use a regular ps credential object instead of manually building your request header.

On a side note, it's always a good idea to test your api out using a tool such as postman. That will let you verify that you're posting valid json while not having to worry about your code doing strange things.

Comment: `Get-Content | Out-String`, `Get-Content -Raw` (PowerShell v3 and newer), or simply putting the variable in double quotes (`-Body "$data"`) would do the same. However, `Invoke-RestMethod` should work fine with an array of lines. Also, if that was causing the error, the `curl` call from the Linux box should have worked.

Comment: Regular PS credentials from get-credential failed auth to Jira.  I tried that before I built the request header.  Also, the .NET call (as opposed to get-content) produces the same result.  **Ansgar** - good call on the curl statement.  I actually went one further - both for the PS script as well as the curl statement: I collapsed the text into a single line to eliminate the possibility that there might be an issue with hidden \n or \t injected by NP++ when i created the text file.

Comment: On a side note - **Trondh** and **Ansgar** - how do I give you guys stars for your help?

Comment: @Brian On SO reputation is usually awarded by upvoting and/or accepting answers. You don't have enough reputation yet to upvote, but if you think Trondh's answer significantly helped in solving the problem you could accept his answer.